# How to retrieve child value from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

**Here is my problem, I want to show all phone numbers in `RecyclerView`, how?**

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("CallLog");
//in on data change method using for
CallLogList logList = snapshot.getValue(CallLogList.class);
                list.add(logList);
```

[image: firebase strucure]

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); map.put("phone",phoneNumber); 
map.put("name",callName);
map.put("callType",dir);
map.put("date",dateString);
map.put("duration",callDuration+" seconds"); 
arrayList.add(map);
myRef.push().setValue(arrayList);
```

Comment: in android devices?

Comment: Jasurbek .... yes how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the whole list from Firebase iterate them one by one to add them in the list, after the loop set them in the adapter of `RecyclerView`, and set the adapter to your desired `RecyclerView`

```
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.
                list = new ArrayList<CallLogList>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                   CallLogList logList = snapshot.getValue(CallLogList.class);
                   list.add(logList);

                }


                yourAdapter = YourAdapter(list);
                yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);


            }
```

For more info, [here](https://www.mytrendin.com/display-firebase-database-items-recyclerview-cardview/) is a full example

Note: If you are using `LiveData` or `Paging` then setting adapters is different, Let me know if you need more example

Comment: i am using live data so i cant change the tree format, is there any other way to retrieve all data in recyclerview.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you, Could you please post your code, it will be easy to help you

Comment: It is just pushing values, Please post the part of the code where you have a problem, Do not post your code here, You can edit your question, so post it question section

Answer (score 1):

First you should change the tree to be like this:

```
Call Log
-Calls
--Lhe...
---CallType OUTGOING
--Lhe...
---CallType INCOMING
```

Next, create "Calls" class in your project with the same fields as in the firebase, so callType, date, duration and phone.
After that, with this code, you can get all instances from the database into a list:

```
    public void refreshList(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Class> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.child("Calls").getChildren()) 
        {
            Item value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(Calls.class);
            list.add(value);
        }
    }
```

Now you have a list of objects of class Calls, from which you can easily access the phone numbers.

Comment: I am doing same but how to retrieve that random numbers ?

Comment: If you want to get the phone number, then just create a getter in the Calls class. If you want the name, so the one that starts with Lhe, then ```dataSnapshot1.key``` should give you this

Comment: how to insert multiple values to firebase ? i am using push method that's why random numbers generated.

Comment: Just make  loop with this code with generating your own IDs:
```
        Calls callToSendd= new Call(callType, date, duration, phone, id);
        mDatabase.child("Calls").child(callToSend.id).setValue(callToSend, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                        //success
                } else {
                        //failed
                }
            }
        });
```